# Element ID not found in jquery....

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I hava an .aspx file and it access to some other .ascx files.  Now, one of the .ascx file has a label, lets say label id="label1". This label1 has a style of style="display: none;".

Now what I want is to display the label using jquery.  So I have this code.

```
$("#<%= label1.ClientID%>").show();
```

I added .ClientID for the .asp appended some other text before the "label1" id.  But when I run my code I got an error "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'label1' does not exist in the current context"

BTW, this is just an illustration, I am currently working on a running application.

Thanks a lot again.

Comment: we can help you better if you also provide the HTML code.

Comment: Looks like there is nothing wrong with the code.. Your project is not compiling in the first place.. It's a error in the code behind file

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <%= YourUserControlID.FindControl("Label1").ClientID %>
```

Applied to your code

```
 $("#<%= YourUserControlID.FindControl("Label1").ClientID %>").show();
```

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'YourUserControlID' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Yha I did it that way, but still, I got the error posted above

Comment: I hope you didn't type 'YourUserControlID' as your control name? Did you replace it with the real UserControlID?

Comment: @codingbiz: some people don't bother reading the code - they only copy and paste. Welcome to the real world :-)

Comment: Sorry, yha zerkms is corrent... hehehe I'll try to change it with my userconrtrol..